# TypeMirror void is not a PrimitiveType since java 8

Tags: java, java-8, primitive-types

I'm migrating a java 7 project to java 8.
There is a method that is doing something like this:

```
if(type instanceof PrimitiveType){
   PrimiriveType type = (Primitivetype) type;
   ...
}
```

In java 7 void Type is an instance of PrimitiveType, but since Java 8 this has changed.

Why had this changed? and what is the Interface that define void types in java 8?

Thanks in advance, Juan

Comment: [It doesn't seem like `void` is supported in either.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/PrimitiveType.html)

Comment: i dont see it is changed void supported either

Comment: If you use `instanceof`, you will learn whether the implementation class happens to implement a particular `interface` which is just an implementation detail. If you don’t want to evaluate implementation details, use the API, i.e. `type.getKind().isPrimitive()`…

Comment: you are totally right, Im doing that now, but there is no isNoType() method, so I ended with bunch of instace of :/

Comment: There is no need for a `isNoType()` method. If you look at [`NoType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/lang/model/type/NoType.html), you’ll see that there are only three possible kinds, `VOID`, `PACKAGE`, and `NONE`, all being mutable exclusive in most contexts. E.g. the only `NoType` which can appear as the return type of a method is `VOID`, hence a simple `type.getKind()==TypeKind.VOID` is sufficient. Similarly, the only `NoType` which can appear as a superclass is `NONE`, etc…and since `TypeKind` is an `enum`, you can use `switch` instead of a bunch of `instanceof`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `void` type is represented by [`javax.lang.model.type.NoType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/NoType.html). But even in Java 7, [`PrimitiveType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/PrimitiveType.html) only includes `boolean`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `char`, `float`, and `double`.

Comment: thanks manouti, I get that those are the only types that PrimitiveType cover, but in java 7 the statement `type instanceof PrimitiveType` is still returning true when type is void. seems weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `javax.lang.model.type.NoType` according to the docs for both [java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/NoType.html) and [java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/NoType.html).